# Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets such that $|A|+|B| = |A \cup C|$ with $C \sim B$ and $A \cap C = \emptyset$ construction of natural number set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets such that
$$|A|+|B| = |A \cup C|$$
with $C \sim B$ and $A \cap C = \emptyset$.
Show that for any choices of $A$ and $B$, we can always found such $C$.
Also, explain its relation to the axiom of natural number.

**Attempt:**

Let
$A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_m \}$ and
$B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots,b_n \}$
for some positive integers $m$ and $n$.
We have $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$.
I can't figure out how to find such $C$.
Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Perform induction on the size of B.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a go at a proof:

Let $|B|=m$, $|A|=n$. Let $A^\prime=A\cap\omega$. If $A^\prime\neq\phi$ then let $r$ be the greatest element of $A^\prime$, using the standard order on the natural numbers (as $A^\prime$ is well-ordered and finite, such an $r$ exists as can be proved by induction). Otherwise let $r=\phi$. Let $C=\{p|p\in\omega\land(r<p)\land(p \le r+m)\}$. Then $A\cap C=\phi, |C|=m$ so $C\approx B$ and $|A\cup C|=m+n$ as $A$ and $C$ are disjoint, and $|A|+|B|=n+m.$

Comment: What is $\omega$?

Comment: @math404 It's the smallest infinite ordinal.  Effectively, it's the set of natural numbers (to make this identification, you have to replace "$r=\phi$" in Porky's argument with "$r=0$", but that's the only necessary change).  The issue is that we have to choose the extra elements of $C$ from _somewhere_, and you haven't specified precisely what our "universe" is.

Comment: Small error fixed :). In words, the proof is to find the largest of the natural numbers in $A$, say $r$, then form the set $C$, {$r+1,r+2,…,r+m}.$

Answer (score 1):

First note that if $C\sim B$ and $A \cap C = \emptyset$, then we always have $$|A|+|B| = |A| + |C| = |A \cup C|,$$
so I won't mention that equation again.  We only need to show there is some $C$ such that $C \sim B$ and $A \cap C = \emptyset$.

---

To show the existence of such a $C$, we induct on $k$ in the following theorem:

> For any finite set $D$, if $|A \cap D| = k$, then there is some set $C$ such that $C \sim D$ and $A \cap C = \emptyset$.

If $k=0$, then we may let $C=D$.

For $k \geq 0$ fixed, we assume by the inductive hypothesis that the above theorem is true.  Now suppose $D$ is a finite set such that $|A \cap D| = k+1 \geq 1$.  Therefore, there is some $x \in A \cap D$, and as $A\cup D$ is a finite set, there is some $y \not\in A\cup D$.  Set $C_0 = (D \setminus \{x\}) \cup \{y\}$.

Then we need to check

- $A \cap C_0 = (A\cap D)\setminus \{x\}$ so that $|A\cap C_0| = |A\cap D| - 1 = k.$
- $C_0 \sim D$

From there, by the inductive hypothesis, there is some $C$ such that $C \sim C_0$ and $A \cap C = 0$.  Finally, since $\sim$ is transitive and $C\sim C_0 \sim D$, it follows that $C \sim D$.

---

That is, the above theorem is true for every natural number $k \geq 0$, so we have the theorem

> For any finite set $D$, there is some set $C$ such that $C \sim D$ and $A\cap C=\emptyset$.

Setting $D = B$ gives just what we were wanting.

Comment: As $y$ is an arbitrary choice, and I think the proof is doing this an infinite number of times,  are you using the axiom of (dependent) choice here?

Comment: @Porky Where are you seeing my choosing $y$ infinitely many times?  I did it once, and selecting a single element can be done just as a matter of first-order logic.  You may prefer the following constructive choice instead: we can define $y = \min\{z \in \omega : z \not\in A\cup D\}$ (which is nonempty by whichever characterization of infinity you want).

Comment: I think you are right. If you make an arbitrary choice during an induction step, it doesn't mean you are using the Axiom of Choice (this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844624/theorem-4-15-page-22-real-and-abstract-analysis-hewitt-and-stromberg does not support the proposition because we are creating a set from the outcome of each induction step).

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for the explanation. Last, what is the relationship between the definition of $|A|+|B|=|A \cup C|$ where $C \sim B$ and $A \cap C = \emptyset$, Sir? Does it about the induction mathematics/Peano's Axiom?